# Is it possible to use a search string url with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

Would any body know if it is possible to search calendar events with a url string?

For example with gMail you could use:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#search/Search+Term
```

to search for the words 'search' and 'term'

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can search Google Calendar using a query parameter in the url:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?q=TERM
```

where TERM is the string you're searching for.

So, you can search using a GET request.

Comment: +1 - Works, and [Kai's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/155387) [question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557902/#4557955) URL (In the update) doesn't look to return anything different than the above URL.

Comment: This URL no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome's dev tools, it appears as though Google Calendar searches are performed using a `POST` request, so you won't be able to pass search terms into urls to fetch a response (which would be a `GET` request).

**Update**: Looks like a `GET` request will still return results, but the response is some form of JSON.

Here is the url (I x'd out my specific info), looks like its not meant for what you want to use it for:

https://www.google.com/calendar/search?ctz=America/New_York&hl=en&as_tp=basic&as_myuids=xxx&as_otheruids=xxx&as_q=kai%20mallea&as_cal=xxx;xxx&secid=xxx

Comment: Cheers Kai, sorry to be a pain but how would I view the requests using chromes dev tools?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, its under View->Developer->Developer Tools and then inspect the Network tab. You should open the page (Google Calendar) with Dev tools open first. Then perform a search and observe the network activity. Also, Firebug is just as good for Firefox -- www.getfirebug.com

Answer (score -1):

A generalization of the current answer is:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/0/render?q=TERM
```

where `0` is the index of the desired Google account (if you have multiple accounts).

Comment: I tried this today and got nothing. Using the search box in the Calendar app resulted in this URL: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/search?q=TERM

Comment: I also see that it fails now.  But so does the original answer I believe.